# Simplex Algorithm: Why does Phase I deliver a BFS immediately?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

When trying to solve a Linear Program (I call it *primary problem* below) of the form

min $c^{T}x$

s.t. $ $ $Ax = b, x \geq 0, b \geq 0 $

The  *two phase simplex algorithm* suggests to starts with the following *auxiliary problem*,

min $\sum y_{i}$

s.t. $Ax + y = b, x \geq 0, b \geq 0 , y \geq 0$

It is argued that a solution to the *auxiliary problem* which gives $\sum y_{i} = 0$, provides a **basic** solution to the primary optimization problem, from which we can initialize the simplex algorithm for the primary problem.

I understand that $\sum y_{i} = 0$ implies that we found a solution to $Ax = b$, and therefore a **feasible solution** to the primary problem, however I do not understand why this solution *must* be a **basic feasible solution**, which implies that at least $n - m$ of the original $n$ decision variables ($x_{i}, i \in \{1, ..., n\}$), are zero.

I would be very grateful if someone could illuminate this.

Comment: I don't think being nonzero is [part of the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_solution_(linear_programming)). What do you think happens in each iteration of the simplex method with regard to the basis?

Comment: Yes sorry I will correct it to 'at least n-m decision variables will be 0'

Comment: Quite a late response but the first couple pages of [these notes](http://sma.epfl.ch/~niemeier/opt09/opt09_ch06.pdf) explain how to ensure your Phase I solution is a BFS for the original problem